# Session variable unset after sending email

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, session-variables

I want to send an email and show notification about it (below is submit function code):

```
Session.set('alertMessage', ['Email has been sent', 'success']);
var a = Session.get('alertMessage');
console.log(a);
Meteor.call('sendEmail', dataText);
```

My SendEmail method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (text) {
  check([text], [String]);
  this.unblock();
  Email.send({
    to: 'myEmail@email.xyz',
    from: 'contactForm@email.xyz',
    subject: 'New message from contact form',
    text: text
  });
}
```

});

And rendered callback of contact form template:

```
Template.contactFormTemplate.rendered = function(){
  var b = Session.get('alertMessage');

  console.log(b);
}
```

The problem: I see in the console that `a` variable gets session value properly:

Array['Email has been sent', 'success']

But after page reload (when form is submitted) `b` variable couldn't get session variable:

```
undefined
```

Even if I try to get this session variable from the console:

```
var c = Session.get('alertMessage')
console.log(c)
```

It returns `undefined` - anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to solve this problem by myself - here's the form submit action code:

```
Session.set('alertMessage', ['Message has been sent.', 'success']);
Meteor.call('sendEmail', dataText);
```

And contact form template rendered callback:

```
Meteor.defer(function(){
  var a = Session.get('alertMessage');
  if(a){
    throwAlert(a[0], a[1]); //my custom method for nicer alert popups
    Session.set('alertMessage', null);
  }
});
```

And finally, I had to add [persistent-session](https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session) package:

```
meteor add u2622:persistent-session
```